# If JVM is allowed to move heap memory during garbage collect then how does garbage collection not cause JNI to explode due to moving pointers?

Tags: java, android, c++, c

Using ByteBuffer is an example; copying data from and Array or a HeapByteBuffer into a DirectByteBuffer performs a JNI call.

*basically this...*

```
public static void copyFromByteArray(byte[] src, long srcPos, long dstAddr, long length)
{
    long offset = arrayBaseOffset + srcPos;
    while (length > 0)
    {
        long size = (length > UNSAFE_COPY_THRESHOLD) ? UNSAFE_COPY_THRESHOLD : length;
        unsafe.copyMemory(src, offset, null, dstAddr, size);
        length -= size;
        offset += size;
        dstAddr += size;
    }
}
```

It uses the magic of calculating the heap pointer and copying directly from the heap.  How is this even remotely safe if that pointer could become invalid in the middle of this routine?

For those concerned: UNSAFE_COPY_THRESHOLD is 1GB

EDIT: Thanks for the replies.  I'm adding the following reference for anyone looking for an answer to the same question.  The process utilizes safepoints (I had no idea what they called it so I couldn't just google it).

References:

- http://blog.ragozin.info/2012/10/safepoints-in-hotspot-jvm.html
- http://chriskirk.blogspot.com/2013/09/what-is-java-safepoint.html

Answer (score 1):

A GC must force all threads into a safepoint to move objects. This means all threads are suspended in a known state, so that all references can be updated safely.

In this case, the unsafe operation is a compiler intrinsic, meaning you do not actually make a call, but the VM inserts machine code implementing the functionality. As this position is not a safepoint, no GC may occur at that position. If a GC becomes necessary, the GC will be postponed until the thread performing the unsafe operation finished this operation and reaches such a safepoint.

Comment: unsafe.copyMemory is a JNI call.  the C code is unsafe and lock free.  It works by converting the object to (uintptr_t) and copying directly from the native memory address.

does this mean that all JNI commands = unsafe state?  I'm trying to understand better what I can get away with.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. You could force a JNI method into all the safe points you like but it will still have direct object pointers of unchanged values afterwards. This answer does not identity the correct mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

All Java objects passed to or obtained by or created by a JNI method are frozen for GC purposes until the method returns. That's why there is a limited number of them.

Comment: I'm concerned about memory addresses of java objects, not pointers. (basically the most unsafe thing you can do)